# "Leaving flowers on your grave / Show that I still care": why is there no Present Simple S to the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, conjugation

In The Offspring's song "Gone Away" there is a line that goes:

"Leaving flowers on your grave

Show that I still care"

and the same goes with the new cover by Five Finger Death Punch, the exact same lyrics that is.

My problem is that: "leaving flowers on your grave" is a noun phrase, a gerund phrase to be exact, with the head word being **leaving**, so the verb that follows **show** should have an S added to it, is it not so?

Thank you.

Comment: Song lyrics like to disregard the "correct" rules of English grammar :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the grammar in the lyrics is incorrect. (I listened to the Offspring version to make sure this wasn't just a mistranscription.) If it's intentional license, I can't see the point of it, and the correct subject is only one word behind the mistaken one so I'm mystified that a native English speaker bungled the wording like that.

[edit] The sentence works if "leaving" was intended to serve as a participle, in the word's sense of "coming into leaf, having emerging leaves", modifying "flowers". "Flowers with emerging leaves on your grave / Show that I still care." But I doubt that was what they had in mind.

Comment: Thank you, i found it very weird and every time i hear it, it bothers my ears.
I thought it might go along the lines of the imperative present simple as in :
it's paramount she study to the test.

Comment: I just added a follow-up paragraph, partly to be sure I'd covered all bases, but mostly because it's far-fetched and possibly amusing.

Answer (score 1):

Song lyrics often have to fit into the available space, causing some words to be omitted. The lyrics could be interpreted as:

> [By] leaving flowers on your grave, [I] show that I still care